# Interval of eigenvalues using Gershgorin circles

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

We have the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0.4 & -0.1 & 0.3 \\ 0.3 & 3 & -0.1 & 0.2 \\ 0 & 0.7 & 3 & 1 \\ 0.2 & 0.1 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$ We get the row Gershgorin circles: $$K_1=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-2|\leq 0.8 \} \\ K_2=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-3|\leq 0.6 \} \\ K_3=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-3|\leq 1.7 \} \\ K_4=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-4|\leq 0.3 \} $$ and the column Gershgorin circles: $$K_1'=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-2|\leq 0.5 \} \\ K_2'=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-3|\leq 1.2 \} \\ K_3'=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-3|\leq 0.2 \} \\ K_4'=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-4|\leq 1.5 \} $$

To get the intervals of the eigenvalues, we have to look at the union of all row circles and the union of all column circles, or not?

Then at the result we have to take the intersection, or not?

$$$$

EDIT:

drawing the row disks we get the following, or not?

[image]

Do we get from that there are complex eigenvalues?

And the column disks:

[image]

right?

Comment: That's correct. You know that all eigenvalues belong to $\bigcup K_i$ and also belong to $\bigcup K_i'$, therefore they belong to $(\bigcup K_i) \cap (\bigcup K_i')$. Notice that $K_i$ and $K_i'$ are disks, not circles and not intervals.

Comment: Does this mean that $\lambda_1$ is in $K_1\cap K_1'$ ? Or can we just say that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4\in (\bigcup K_i) \cap (\bigcup K_i')$ ? @Maxim

Comment: No, there isn't a one-to-one correspondence (consult the Wikipedia article on the Gershgorin circle theorem). In particular, there are no eigenvalues inside $K_3'$. Also, how do you order complex eigenvalues?

Comment: If they are on the x-axis they are real, if not they are complex, or not? Do we get the following inequalities? From the row disks: $$1.2\leq \lambda_1 \leq 2.8 \\ 2.4\leq \lambda_2\leq 3.6 \\ 1.3 \leq \lambda_3\leq 4.7 \\ 3.7 \leq \lambda_4\leq 4.3$$ and from the column disks: $$1.5 \leq \lambda_5\leq 2.5 \\ 1.8 \leq \lambda_6\leq 4.2 \\ 2.8 \leq \lambda_7\leq 3.2 \\ 2.5\leq \lambda_8\leq 5.5$$ So is then the result $$1.2\leq \lambda_1, \lambda_5\leq 2.8 \\ 1.8\leq \lambda_2, \lambda_6\leq 4.2 \\ 1.3 \leq \lambda_3, \lambda_7\leq 4.7 \\ 2.5\leq \lambda_4, \lambda_8\leq 5.5$$ @Maxim

Comment: No, you cannot say that because you don't know whether your eigenvalues are real or complex (and in fact two of them are complex non real). See the picture I am going to post.

Comment: What are $\lambda_5$ to $\lambda_8$?

Comment: They have to be the same as $\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_4$ just in an other order? @Maxim

Comment: How do you know that they're real (meaning that they lie on the $x$-axis)? In fact some of them are not. $z \in \mathbb C$ being inside the disk centered at $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ with radius $r$ means that $|z - z_0| \leq r$. It's a disk in the complex plane.

Comment: I got stuck right now. How do we know looking at the disks if the eigenvalues are real or complex? Or can we not see that from there? I think that if there is a unique eigenvalue in a disk it must be real, since otherwise its complex should also be there. Is this correct? @Maxim

Comment: Yes, the last statement is correct. The characteristic polynomial has real coefficients, so non-real roots come in conjugate pairs. And the disks are centered on the real axis.

Comment: So drwaing the row disks we get some inequalities and drawing the column disks we get als some inequalities for the real eigenvalues or not? @Maxim

Comment: That's right. For real eigenvalues you can take the intersection of the two unions of the diameters. But again, there won't be an eigenvalue in the interval corresponding to $K_3'$.